# setMovementMethod doesn't work in android textview if textView used in container

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview

I use `TextView` as a layout in container.

myTextView.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_left"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="10dp
        android:lineSpacingExtra="2dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:fontFamily="@font/helvetica_roman"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp">    
</TextView>
```

and this layout I use in container:

```
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/myContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="14dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/ic1"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/ic2" />
```

and part of my code:

```
LinearLayout myContainer = findViewById(R.id.privilegesListContainer);
    TextView text = (TextView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.myTextView, myContainer, false);
                        text.setText(getString(R.string.my_link));
                        text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                        myContainer.addView(text);
```

strings.xml:

```
<string name="my_link"><a href='http://www.google.com'> Google </a></string>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the link in double quotes instead of single one, like this:

```
<string name="my_link"><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></string>
```

Comment: thanks for comment. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As an option, if you want to automaticcaly make hyperlinks visible and clickable, you can parse provided text as HTML when setting it to the TextView:

```
text.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.my_link)));
```